# toggleClass not working on slider

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use .toggleClass to change the class on a link in order to swap a background image from a plus to a minus when the toggle is open/closed. It seems to be referencing the correct piece of the code as I can see in Firebug that it tries to change the class, but the change doesn't actually happen. Here is the code that I have:

```
<div class="slide-click-container">
<a href="#" class="slide-click-link">
    Click here to expand/contract

    <span class="control-arrow"><!-- PLUS/MINUS SIGN BACKGROUND IMAGE HERE --></span>
</a>

<div class="slider hide"> <!-- HIDE CLASS SETS DIV TO DISPLAY:NONE -->
    Content here
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(".slide-click-container").click(function(ev){
ev.preventDefault();
$(this).find(".slider").slideToggle('slow');
$(this).find(".control-arrow").toggleClass('open');
});

</script>
```

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Jamie

Comment: Are you sure your element .control-arrow has width? like using css similar to: `.control-arrow { width:14px; display:inline-block; }`  I tested your code with that css and it seems to work then. http://jsfiddle.net/nX7J5/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `find` for this.

```
$(".slide-click-container").click(function(ev){
   ev.preventDefault();
   $(".slider").slideToggle('slow');
   $(".control-arrow").toggleClass('open');
 });
```

EDIT:
Use `next` and `closest` instead

```
$(".slide-click-container").click(function(ev){
   ev.preventDefault();
   $(this).parent().next().slideToggle('slow');
   $(this).closest(".control-arrow").toggleClass('open');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Asdine. I see it now works with find, but unfortunately I have several of these sliders on the page, so I'm using .find to only target the specific slider that is being toggled. Is there a way to use toggleClass with .find?

Comment: using find should work ok in this instance given the requirement

Comment: Thanks Mark. It doesn't seem to be doing though, at least not with how I have it set out above.

Answer (score 0):

Give your class some layout and some content:

```
.control-arrow {
    width:14px;
    display:inline-block;
 }
```

and a fixed space:

```
<span class="control-arrow">&nbsp;<!-- PLUS/MINUS SIGN BACKGROUND IMAGE HERE --></span>
```